# Proving that a convergent infinite series implies convergent part of that series and vice versa

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am asked to prove the following theorem:

> $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=N}^\infty$ converges.

I am not sure if I have done this correctly:

Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. We have that $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n + \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$. Seeing as a convergent term cannot be a sum of a divergent one, we have that convergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ implies convergent $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$.

Suppose conversely that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ is convergent. We have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n - \sum_{n=1}^{N - 1} a_n = \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$. By the same logic as before, we have that convergent $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ implies convergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

Comment: I believe this requires more rigorous proofs than what you did. For example, you do not know that $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n + \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ before you prove the sums exist. To me, a convincing proof would include limits of partial sums.

Comment: Why wouldn't the sums exist?  Isn't he just manipulating indices here?

Comment: @Patrick: No, because one of the limits on the indices is $\infty$.

Comment: @5xum, that follows directly. Either both sides exist or neither does.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, it does not follow directly. It follows simply, and yes, maybe you do not have to prove it (depending on the level of your course). However, you must understand why it follows and be able to prove it should need arise. If you are not able to prove it, you do not have the right to say it follows directly. As a professor always said to me: "'obvious' is a word you get to use once you have a PhD."

Comment: @AndrewThompson After rereading your argument, I am even more convinced that you cannot say what you are saying. Basically, the sentence "Either both sides exist or neither does" is equivalent to the sentence "either both sums converge or neither does". Since this is what you want to prove, I am 100% certain you cannot simpliy assume that it is correct.